# Using ASP.NET with MySQL as default database?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

Im creating a ASP.NET site, but i dont want to use SqlServer i want to use my pre-existing MySQL database as the default connection. ive set up a new schema for it and assigned a user, and changed my default connection string to this

```
<add name="DefaultConnection"  connectionString="Server=THEIP;Database=THESCHEMANAME;Uid=THEUSER;Pwd=THEPASSWORD;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

It seems to be able to connect to the DB alright (as far as i can tell?) 
so now i figured i needed to change the default membership provider so that the login is ran through this connection, i did some looking around on the net and found this on the MySQL site

```
<add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" autogenerateschema="true" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"  />
```

So i replaced my default membership provider with this, ran the site from Visual Studio, went to /Account/Register.aspx (every other page works alright as of yet) and i get this error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Can anybody point out what ive done wrong?

Comment: Did you also install the MySQL driver? See http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ and http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html

Comment: I used the MySQL installer and installed "MySQL for Visual Studio 1.0.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the assembly was wrong, i went into the refrence assemblies and found that the version is not '6.0.4.0' but is infact '6.6.5.0', changed the version no. and its all working fine now.